# VP8 and VP9 support in mobile phone

Tags: h.264, vp8

Which mobile phones support VP8 and VP9 video compression format?
Otherwise can we convert a H.264 compatible phone to VP8 / VP9 supported?

Answer (score 0):

Android already has VP8 support, see the details here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html